# Issues when trying to deploy project (Firebase Functions/Hosting)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

When running a command `firebase deploy` I receive 2 errors:

```
  10:8  error  'onRequest' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

  11:7  error  'logger' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
```

Followed by:

```
functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1
```

I assume it's related to my index.js file inside Functions folder but I've never changed it or used it before (also not sure why some parts are commented out).

```js
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
 * const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */

const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

// exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
//   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
```

What should I do to fix this and be able to deploy the app?

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment `// exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => { //   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true}); //   response.send("Hello from Firebase!"); // });`